# Is there a way to center the current line vertically in the Eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a functionality similar to Ctrl-l in Emacs. What it does is, for example, if you are editing the second-last line in the visible editor window and you hit `Ctrl-L`, the current line will move to the center of the editor screen.

This works regardless of the file end.
Most of the time, if one is creating a new file, they would be at the last line, adding more content to the file. Continually staring at the bottom of the screen is hurting my neck.

Comment: Have you though about raising your monitor a bit? A couple of copies of `War and Peace` or a phone book are ideal for this, not so the collected wisdom of George W Bush :-)

Comment: May be not collected wisdom but definitely collected wisdomisms ;) That's what I will do if I don't find anything else.

Comment: Yes, ctrl+L centers as long as it's not the very last

Answer (score 3):

- Go to *Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Keys*
- Filter the commands to find 'Recenter'
- Add preferred binding (I have Ctrl+Shift+B)
- Select 'Editing Text' in the *When* dropdown.

Edit: unfortunately, if the cursor is at the end of the file, and you try to "recenter", it won't work because there is nothing left to show below the cursor.

Comment: I have recenter configured but as you said, it does not work if the cursor is close to the end of file, which is where I am most of the time. Perhaps I should add a half-page footer.

Comment: Frustrating indeed!  However, not sure this is actually possible with the editor panes used in SWT...

Comment: You may need to change the WHEN to 'Editing Java Source' or whatever source you use.  'Editing Text' may not apply to the editor you are using.